# Run function few hours before event occurs

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have one problem. I am learning cakephp 3 and I want to do the folowing:
User enters date and time (this is saved into mysql as datetime format) and system needs to send email few hours before this datetime that he enters (for example, 1 hour before)

However, I want to do this without cronjob.

So user enters 2019-05-12 12:00 and I want immediately to schedule task to send email on 2019-05-12 at 11:00.

Is this possible and yes, can you please give me any pointers? I also checked cakephp tasks, but it seems that I don’t see the whole picture yet

Comment: Sounds like you want [queueing](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue), either immediately or with timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create Shell

```
bin/cake bake shell CronJobs
```

open created shell and create method to send email, for example:

```
public function sendEmal()
{
}
```

Inside this method add your code to select data and Mailer to send mail.

now in your cron tab set task and point to this shell script, example

```
* 1 * * * bin/cake CronJob sendEmail
```

Please read:

1. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/shells.html
2. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html
3. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html

Update:

> However, I want to do this without cronjob.

Other way is to implement some Queue system.

Read [**here**](https://www.codementor.io/smorhaim/creating-simple-powerful-queue-system-beanstalkd-microservices-du107kllb) for more information

Comment: Yes, however, I wrote in my question this: "However, I want to do this without cronjob."

Comment: Well, then write your own cronjob like implementation that runs in the background (re-invent the wheel) or do it manually. ;) It is pretty obvious that you need something running in a loop in the background triggering something at a given time. No way around that logic.